# How to remove a particular bin from path/auto-complete?

Tags: paths, auto-completion

I don't have sudo privileges on my work laptop and `tmuxinator` is installed, but I wish to use `tmuxifier` instead. I successfully installed the latter (without needing `sudo` by using `git`), but now, annoyingly, I can't type `tmuxi`, then hit <kbd>Tab</kbd> in the terminal and have it resolve to `tmuxifier`, as it's ambiguous.

`tmuxinator` is installed inside `/usr/...`, so I don't have permission to rename it.

What's the quickest/cleanest way to have `tmuxi-` resolve to tmuxi**fier** without the ability to uninstall or move `tmuxinator`?

Comment: https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/314631/70524

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As [@muru suggested](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1481275/how-to-remove-a-particular-bin-from-path-auto-complete#comment2593746_1481275), use the bash variable [`EXECIGNORE`](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/314631/hide-some-commands-from-bash-completion) to ignore `tmuxinator`. Add it at the end of your `.bashrc` file with:

```
echo 'EXECIGNORE="*/tmuxinator:$EXECIGNORE"' >> ~/.bashrc
```

Then relaunch your terminal and you’re done.

**Note**: Here we append the `$EXECIGNORE` variable to not erase its content.